# Counting differences from the consensus in each row via Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, consensus

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c','d'],'B':['a','b','c','x'],'C':['y','b','c','d']})
df

   A  B  C
0  a  a  y
1  b  b  b
2  c  c  c
3  d  x  d
```

I want to identify the most common character in each row, and total the number of differences from the consensus:

```
       A  B  C Consensus
    0  a  a  y         a
    1  b  b  b         b
    2  c  c  c         c
    3  d  x  d         d
Total  0  1  1         0
```

Running through loops is one approach, but it seems inefficient:

```
consensus = []
for idx in df.index:
    consensus.append(df.loc[idx].value_counts().index[0])
df['Consensus'] = consensus
```

(and so on)

Is there a straightforward way to get the consensus and count differences from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `mode` to get the consensus value:

```
>>> df.mode(axis=1)
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
```

Note the caveats in the docs though:

> Gets the mode(s) of each element along the axis selected. Empty if nothing has 2+ occurrences. Adds a row for each mode per label, fills in gaps with nan.
>
> Note that there could be multiple values returned for the selected axis (when more than one item share the maximum frequency), which is the reason why a dataframe is returned. If you want to impute missing values with the mode in a dataframe df, you can just do this: df.fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])

To count the *differences* from the consensus for each column you could compare with `ne` and then sum:

```
>>> df['consensus'] = df.mode(axis=1)
>>> df.loc[:, 'A':'C'].ne(df['consensus'], axis=0).sum(axis=0)
A    0
B    1
C    1
dtype: int64
```